# Should all Firebase notifications open at the same time for iOS Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase Messaging into my Flutter app. Everything is working fine for Android. On iOS, if I received 2 or more push notifications, when I open one of those push notifications or bring the app to the foreground, onResume is triggered for all of the notifications at the same time and all of the notification are removed from my lock screen. I would expect onResume to only get called for the selected notification and onResume not getting called at all if the app is opened or brought to the foreground without interacting with the notification banner. That is how it's working for Android.

Is this the expected behavior or is there a way around this?

**UPDATE**

I removed `content_available: true` from my payload and that stopped onResumed from getting called multiple times when the app is launched/resumed, but the unopened notifications are still disappearing.